# Default language AD users 1.3 - Sitecore 8.2.u2

Tags: user-profile, editor-user-permissions, user-management, active-directory-module

> "The security settings for the current language prevent you from seeing this item"

New users from the AD tries to reach the English version of the site, because their Default Content Language is set to "Default". I want to set this to Swedish when the user is created.

Below is how a new users "Language Settings" look.

[image]

I want this to be set to Swedish, automatically, from the creation of the user. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

So I found that this was connected to a new config file that came with my upgrade to this version.

**/App_Config/Include/Sitecore.DefaultLanguage.config**.

I thought this was related to the AD since it worked in the past. I already had changes done to the sitecore.config for

ContentLanguage

Language

ClientLanguage

This was overwritten by the **Sitecore.DefaultLanguage.config.**.
Make sure you disabled it by adding .disabled after config and it solved my problem.